# Реализация метода Put(), getByKey для кастомного HashMap

Tags: java, коллекции

Вопрос с собеседования:"нужно реализовать свои `Put()` и `getByKey`, для хеш-мапы." Может кто-то подсказать, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Зачем это надо?

Comment: Не имею ни малейшего представления, но со слов тим лида, который проводил собеседование - это для того, чтобы представлять как вся эта химера работает внутри.

Comment: Нужно знать *что* реализовывать, а *как* это я уже написал в своем ответе.

Comment: ну вам же тим лид и ответил, что надо посмотреть как HashMap работает, разобраться и для закрепления реализовать самому. если лень разбираться с исходниками, ищем на хабре "hashmap" и читаем https://habr.com/post/128017/

Comment: Мне кажется, тимлид хотел узнать о том, есть ли у вас базовые знания о структурах данных, а не о том, умеете ли вы писать вопросы на stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Создать класс MyMap и статический вложенный класс для связей, поле int hash в Вашем случае можно опустить, подумай как реализовать методы сам и какие поля в классе MyMap нужны

```
public class MyMap<K,V> {
 void Put(K, V) {
  //do something..
  }
 K getByKey {
  //do something
  return K;
 }

    static class Node<K,V> {
        final int hash;
        final K key;//ключ
        V value;//значение
        Node<K,V> next;//ссылка на след. элемент

      Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
        this.hash = hash;
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
      }
    }
}
```